# I want to fetch weather data based on the users geolocation. Thought I had this figured out but I don't

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, geolocation, fetch

I'm sure this has to do with the timing geolocation and axios fetching the data. With useEffect
it will give the wrong location. If I call the function without useEffect I will get the correct location but this creates an infinite loop. I've also tried using a condition in the useEffect.
and have tried using setTimeout;

How do I make sure navigator.geolocation has the lat and long before fetching the data?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './css/weather.css'
import axios from 'axios';


const Weather = () => {
      const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
      const [long, setLong] = useState(0);
      const [temp, setTemp] = useState(0);

      const [wind, setWind] = useState('');
      const [windDir, setWindDir] = useState('');
      const [gust, setGust] = useState('');
      const [precip, setPrecip] = useState(0);
      const [icon, setIcon] = useState('');
      const [pic, setPic] = useState('');
      const [city, setCity] = useState('');
      
      const getWeather = async () => {

            try {
                  await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
                        setLong(position.coords.longitude);
                  })
                  const response = await axios.get(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=6e6263afb84f44279f731543222510&q=${lat},${long}&aqi=no`);
                  console.log(response.data)
                  setCity(response.data.location.name)
                  setTemp(response.data.current.temp_f);
                  setWind(response.data.current.wind_mph);
                  setWindDir(response.data.current.wind_dir);
                  setGust(response.data.current.gust_mph);
                  setPrecip(response.data.current.precip_in);
                  setPic(response.data.current.condition.icon.slice(-7))

                  if(response.data.current.condition.icon.includes('day')){
                        setIcon(<img src={`/assets/weather/64x64/day/${pic}`}></img> 
                        )
                  } else {
                        setIcon(<img src={`/assets/weather/64x64/night/${pic}`}></img> )
               
                  }

            
            } catch (err) {
                  console.error(err)
            }
      }

useEffect(() =>{

getWeather();
      
},[])
      

      return (
            <div className='weather-container'>
                  <p>{icon}</p>
                  <h2>{city}</h2>
                  <p>{`Current Temp: ${Math.round(temp)} °F`}</p>
                  <p>{`Wind: ${windDir} ${Math.round(wind)} mph Gusts: ${Math.round(gust)} mph`}</p>
                  <p>{`Precip: ${Math.round(precip)}in`}</p>
            </div>
      )

}



export default Weather;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. Putting lat in `useEffect` as an dependency seems to have solved the problem.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getWeather();
}, [lat]);
```